# Multiple matrix multiplication loses weight updates

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

When in `forward` method I only do one set of `torch.add(torch.bmm(x, exp_w), self.b)` then my model is back propagating correctly. When I add another layer - `torch.add(torch.bmm(out, exp_w2), self.b2)` - then the gradients are not updated and the model isn't learning. If I change the activation function from `nn.Sigmoid` to `nn.ReLU` then it works with two layers.

Been thinking about this a day now, and not figuring out why it's not working with `nn.Sigmoid`.

I've tried different learning rates, Loss functions and optimization functions, but no combination seems to work. When I add the weights together before and after training they are the same.

Code:

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim):
        torch.manual_seed(1)
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        hidden_1_dimentsions = 20
        self.w = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.empty(input_dim, hidden_1_dimentsions).uniform_(0, 1))
        self.b = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.empty(hidden_1_dimentsions).uniform_(0, 1))

        self.w2 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.empty(hidden_1_dimentsions, output_dim).uniform_(0, 1))
        self.b2 = torch.nn.Parameter(torch.empty(output_dim).uniform_(0, 1))

    def activation(self):
        return torch.nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view((x.shape[0], 1, self.input_dim))

        exp_w = self.w.expand(x.shape[0], self.w.size(0), self.w.size(1))
        out = torch.add(torch.bmm(x, exp_w), self.b)
        exp_w2 = self.w2.expand(out.shape[0], self.w2.size(0), self.w2.size(1))
        out = torch.add(torch.bmm(out, exp_w2), self.b2)
        out = self.activation()(out)
        return out.view(x.shape[0])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides loss functions, activation functions and learning rates, your parameter initialisation is also important. I suggest you to take a look at Xavier initialisation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.init.xavier_uniform_

Furthermore, for a wide range of problems and network architectures Batch Normalization, which ensures that your activations have zero mean and standard deviation, helps: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.BatchNorm1d

If you are interested to know more about the reason for this, it's mostly due to the vanishing gradient problem, which means that your gradients get so small that your weights don't get updated. It's so common that it has its own page on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanishing_gradient_problem

Comment: But how could I test, that it's vanishing gradient problem? Right now when I look the gradients I can't see them being updated at all, even when I set learning larger so the gradients should be larger.

Comment: @MihkelL. The learning rate doesn't influence the gradients itself, it influences how the gradients are applied to the weights. So increasing the learning rates doesn't influence the gradients. You can check the magnitude of the activations before you pass them to the sigmoid function. If their magnitude is large, the gradient will be very small. Furthermore, I just found that you are not applying the activations between the two layers (i.e. after `torch.add(torch.bmm(x, exp_w), self.b)`), so that you are just concatenating two linear operations resulting in a single matrix multiplication.

Comment: right I left it to the end. Thanks for pointing it out. And batch normalization indeed helped. I'll look it up if I can see the vanishing gradient symptom myself. :)